# How do I properly install the StarUML software?

Tags: windows, installation

Can someone please step by step explain to me how to install StarUML software? I've downloaded and unzipped it but other than that I'm just unable to go any further with this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you clicked on the big green download button. Unfortunately that downloads the source and my guess is that you want [staruml-5.0-with-cm.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/staruml/files/staruml/5.0/staruml-5.0-with-cm.exe/download) instead.

[image]